# Do Web APIs run in other threads?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, settimeout, webapi

I have a presentation to make and I need to make sure of something.

I know that JavaScript runs in a single thread (except for the use of workers) and have a good understanding of the execution context in general.

Now, when you use a function like setTimeout or addEventListener, the Web APis manage the timer of setTimeout / listen to events then push the callback to the queue at the right time.

The timer management / event listening operations are outside the scope of JavaScript. My question is: are these operations executed concurrently or are they executed in parallel (hence in other threads)?

Comment: [Everything You Need to Know About Node.js Event Loop - Bert Belder, IBM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNa9OMajw9w)

Comment: What do you mean by "*systematically*"? Why multiple threads? If you mean "every web api call runs in a new thread": definitely not.